# gulp.watch() not running subsequent task

Tags: javascript, frontend, gulp

Running into a bizarre bug when trying to make modular gulp tasks by splitting them into separate files. The following should execute the task `css`, but does not:

### File: `watch.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  plugins.watch('assets/styl/**/*.styl', ['css']); // PROBLEM
});
```

Declaring `['css']` in `plugins.watch()` should technically run the following task next:

### File: `css.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('assets/styl/*.styl')
    .pipe(plugins.stylus())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/assets/css'));
});
```

### File: `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });

gulp.task('develop', ['css', 'watch']);
```

### Folder structure

`- gulp/
   - tasks/
      - css.js
      - watch.js
- gulpfile.js`

---

## Expected behavior

`gulp develop` should run tasks `css` and `watch` (it does). On file changes, `watch` should detect them (it does) and then run the `css` task (it's does not).

### One solution

Not terribly fond of this solution as `gulp.start()` is being deprecated in the next release, but this does fix it:

#### File: `watch.js`

```
plugins.watch('assets/styl/**/*.styl', function() {
  gulp.start('css');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use gulp's [builtin watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#tasks) with this syntax:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('assets/styl/**/*.styl', ['css']);
});
```

Or [gulp-watch plugin](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#starting-tasks-on-events) with this syntax:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  plugins.watch('assets/styl/**/*.styl', function (files, cb) {
    gulp.start('css', cb);
  });
});
```

There's also probably a typo in your gulp.dest path. Change it to relative:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Gulp 4, where gulp.start() is deprecated

So here's the solution

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('some-task-name', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: config.distFolder + ''
        }
    });

    var watcher = gulp.watch([
                    './src/views/*.html', 
                    './src/index.html', 
                    './src/assets/css/*.css', 
                    './src/**/*.js'],
                    gulp.series('some-task-name'));
    watcher.on('change', async function (path, stats) {
        console.log('you changed the code');
        browserSync.notify("Compiling, please wait!");
        browserSync.reload();
    })
}));
```

Now, whenever there is a change in my code, my "some-task-name" gets executed and then the browser page is reloaded. I don't need to delay my browser-sync at all.