# gulp-watch doesn't update gulp-jshint

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

what's wrong with this code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var stylish = require('jshint-stylish');

//lint
module.exports = gulp.task('lint', function () {
  return gulp.src([config.paths.src.scripts,config.paths.exclude.bower])
  .pipe(jshint())
  .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});

//watch
module.exports = gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch(config.paths.src.scripts, ['lint'])
        .pipe(connect.reload());
    watch(config.paths.src.templates, ['templates'])
        .pipe(connect.reload());
    watch(config.paths.src.index)
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

when ie I edit a js file doing an error
jshint show me nothing.

This works:

```
watch(config.paths.src.scripts)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
```

but it's quite the same or not ?

Comment: Double `module.exports` seems quite suspicious. Are those tasks in separate files?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476226/gulp-watch-not-running-subsequent-task/26480579#26480579

Comment: @Heikki Yes they are I've loaded it like https://gist.github.com/whisher/102a89b75a7ef554bd52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gulp-watch does not support an array of task names like the internal gulp.watch. See documentation at https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch

You have to provide gulp-watch a function, something like

```
watch(config.paths.src.scripts, function(events, done) {
   gulp.start(['lint'], done);
}
```

Note: It seems that gulp.start will be deprecated in Gulp 4.x, it will be replaced by a task runner called bach: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/92